# Angular Highcharts dynamic x-axis not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

> How to generate the dynamic x-axis and how to render in the charts,

**Package.json**

> Version used

```
enter code here"angular-highcharts": "5.2.12"
```

**app.module.ts**

> importing highchart module in app module

```
import { ChartModule, HIGHCHARTS_MODULES } from 'angular-highcharts';
providers: [
    {
      provide: HIGHCHARTS_MODULES,
      useFactory: highchartsModules
    },

  ]
```

**app.component.ts**

> Creating dynamic x-axis by json,but x-axis showing empty.

```
        import { Chart,Highcharts } from 'angular-highcharts';
    public adherenceData = new Chart({
        chart: {
          type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
          text: ''
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
          labels:{
            enabled:false
          },
          categories: [],
          crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          title: {
            text: 'Percentage'
          }
        },
        legend:{
          enabled:false
        },
        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
          },
          series:{
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: 0,
                color: '#000000',
                align: 'right',
                format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
                y: 0, // 10 pixels down from the top
                x: 0,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '12px'
                }
            }
          },
        },
        series: []
      }
      );
    let cArr=[]
    response.payload.forEach((e,i)=>{
crArr.push(e.username)
              this.adherenceData.addSerie({'name': e.username,'data':[e.visitAdherence]} , true,{
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'easeOutBounce'
              })
```

> In CArr the values for x-axis are pushed and passing to x-axis
>   category

```
    this.adherenceData.options.xAxis[0].categories = cArr;
       this.adherenceData.ref.redraw();
})
```

> In result img x-axis showing empty

**Result:** [image: img]

Comment: can you try this in your chart `xAxis: { labels:{ enabled:true }` instead of `xAxis: { labels:{ enabled:false }` this.

Comment: Use `xAxis[0].update({categories: [\*your categories*\]})` on the chart's object after you generated the categories dynamically: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Answer (score 0):

You may try the chart method setCategories as in `chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(curr)` and then redraw.
I would usually set categories using this method.

Comment: The xaxis isn't available in this way in the angular version (which is highly annoying). chart.redraw isn't available either (*sigh*)